# Como asignar un valor a nodo faltante en xml, con Phyton

Tags: python, xml

Tengo una función que recorre un xml que es una factura, la factura trae la información del producto, precio, cantidad, código de impuesto monto del impuesto y monto total entre otros, toda la información es cargada sin problemas por la función.
El problema que tengo es que algunas líneas de productos vienen sin el nodo de impuestos por lo que en algunas líneas me falta el dato del cosido del impuesto.
Como asignar un valor especifico del 1 al 10 al código del impuesto en caso que en la línea del producto no exista.

Este seria un ejemplo del XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DetalleServicio>

<LineaDetalle>

<NumeroLinea>7</NumeroLinea>

<Codigo>2399502009900</Codigo>

<CodigoComercial>

<Tipo>01</Tipo>

<Codigo>033844000240</Codigo>

</CodigoComercial>

<Cantidad>3</Cantidad>

<UnidadMedida>Unid</UnidadMedida>

<Detalle>CONDIMENTO BADIA PIM. NEGRA MOL. 14G</Detalle>

<PrecioUnitario>607.21978</PrecioUnitario>

<MontoTotal>1821.65934</MontoTotal>

<SubTotal>1821.65934</SubTotal>

<Impuesto>

<Codigo>01</Codigo>

<CodigoTarifa>08</CodigoTarifa>

<Tarifa>13</Tarifa>

<Monto>236.81571</Monto>

</Impuesto>

<ImpuestoNeto>236.81571</ImpuestoNeto>

<MontoTotalLinea>2058.47505</MontoTotalLinea>

</LineaDetalle>


<LineaDetalle>

<NumeroLinea>8</NumeroLinea>

<Codigo>2399502000100</Codigo>


<CodigoComercial>

<Tipo>01</Tipo>

<Codigo>088169407663</Codigo>

</CodigoComercial>

<Cantidad>3</Cantidad>

<UnidadMedida>Unid</UnidadMedida>

<Detalle>CONSOME POLLO MAGGI 1X4 10 G</Detalle>

<PrecioUnitario>453.07212</PrecioUnitario>

<MontoTotal>1359.21636</MontoTotal>

<SubTotal>1359.21636</SubTotal>


<Impuesto>

<Codigo>01</Codigo>

<CodigoTarifa>02</CodigoTarifa>

<Tarifa>1</Tarifa>

<Monto>13.59216</Monto>

</Impuesto>

<ImpuestoNeto>13.59216</ImpuestoNeto>

<MontoTotalLinea>1372.80852</MontoTotalLinea>

</LineaDetalle>


<LineaDetalle>

<NumeroLinea>2</NumeroLinea>

<Codigo>2111300020100</Codigo>


<CodigoComercial>

<Tipo>01</Tipo>

<Codigo>605007</Codigo>

</CodigoComercial>

<Cantidad>1.665</Cantidad>

<UnidadMedida>Unid</UnidadMedida>

<Detalle>CHULETA DE CERDO</Detalle>

<PrecioUnitario>3762.38</PrecioUnitario>

<MontoTotal>6264.36270</MontoTotal>

<SubTotal>6264.36270</SubTotal>

<ImpuestoNeto>62.64363</ImpuestoNeto>

<MontoTotalLinea>6327.00633</MontoTotalLinea>

</LineaDetalle>
```

**la ultima Linea detalle es la que no tiene el codigo de impuesto.**
Alguno me recomendaria un for para recorrer la **linea detalle** y obtener los datos de cada producto y que cuando no existe el nodo de impuesto le asigne un valor especifico al codigo del impuesto y al codigo de tarifa.

Este seria el fragmento del codigo que extrae en codigo del impuesto y de la tarifa

```
    total_tax = 0.0
                taxes = []
                tax_nodes = line.xpath("inv:Impuesto", namespaces=namespaces)
                for tax_node in tax_nodes:
                    tax_code = re.sub(r"[^0-9]+", "", tax_node.xpath("inv:Codigo", namespaces=namespaces)[0].text)
                    tax_amount = float(tax_node.xpath("inv:Tarifa", namespaces=namespaces)[0].text)
                    _logger.debug('FECR - tax_code: %s', tax_code)
                    _logger.debug('FECR - tax_amount: %s', tax_amount)
    
                    if product_id and product_id.non_tax_deductible:
                        tax = invoice.env['account.tax'].search([('tax_code', '=', tax_code),
                                                                 ('amount', '=', tax_amount),
                                                                 ('type_tax_use', '=', 'purchase'),
                                                                 ('non_tax_deductible', '=', True),
                                                                 ('active', '=', True)], limit=1)
                    else:
                        tax = invoice.env['account.tax'].search([('tax_code', '=', tax_code),
                                                                 ('amount', '=', tax_amount),
                                                                 ('type_tax_use', '=', 'purchase'),
                                                                 ('non_tax_deductible', '=', False),
                                                                 ('active', '=', True)], limit=1))
```

Comment: Creo que has puesto demasiado código innecesario para entender lo qué preguntas. Te recomiendo que crees un [ejemplo mínimo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para entender el problema y así haya más gente que se anime a responder. Si bien entiendo la pregunta, hay entradas que no tienen datos sobre los impuestos. Para detectarlas no te queda otra que subir de nivel. En lugar de buscar los nodos `"<Impuesto>"` tendrás que hacerlo sobre los nodos `"<LineaDetalle>"`.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, creo que mejor elimino el codigo.

Comment: De hecho, no. Pon el código en el que estás intentando manipular el archivo y cualquier error que tengas o la salida esperada, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Con Python y otras lenguas, se puede utilizar XSLT para transformar XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="LineaDetalle[not(Impuesto)]/SubTotal">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <Impuesto>
      <Codigo></Codigo>
      <CodigoTarifa></CodigoTarifa>
      <Tarifa></Tarifa>
      <Monto></Monto>
    </Impuesto>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Este ejemplo solo añade elementos vacios sin datos pero no he entendido bien de donde se saca los datos. https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt describe como aplicar XSLT con Python.

Comment: Tengo un for que recorre un XML de una factura para ser importados a la parte de compras de mi sistema, en la factura por cada producto existe una linea y en unas lineas del produto existe el nodo de impuesto y en otras no existe el nodo de impuesto. El logro importar todos los datos de la factura sin problemas solo que cuando el nodo de impuesto no existe deja la celda de impuesto en blanco. Lo que no logro hacer es que cuando se importes los datos del XML y el nodo de impuestos no existe asigne un valor fijo a la celda del impuesto.

Comment: La plantilla `<xsl:template match="LineaDetalle[not(Impuesto)]/SubTotal">` solo se aplica a elementos LineaDetalle sin un elemento Impuesto y dentro se hace una copia de SubTotal y se añade un elemento Impuesto con los elementos Codigo, CodigoTarifa, Tarifa, Monto. No he puesto ningun valor dentro de estos elementos pero podrías utilizar cualquier valor fijo.